# how to get access to vuex inside other js files like plugins in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

i have a problem. i wanna get access to one of my getters inside my vee-validate.js file.
how can i do that?

in my pages and components, (in `<script>...</script>` part, outside `export default{...}`) i used this function:

component.vue

```
<script>
let lang;
function getLang({store}) {
    lang = store.state.lang
}

export default{
   ...
}
```

but it is not working!

i'm trying to access my custom lang file (for translation purpose) that is stored in `lang` state in my vuex, and use it in vee-validate.js file for custom message.

i tried to import `store` but not working.
veevalidate.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { required } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules'
import { extend, ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider, setInteractionMode } from 'vee-validate'

import {store} from '../store'
let langFile = store

setInteractionMode('eager')

extend('required', {
    ...required,
    message: ''
})

Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider);
Vue.component("ValidationObserver", ValidationObserver);
```

**UPDATED:** My store index.js

```
import langfile from '../static/lang'

export const state = () => ({
  lang: null,
  dir: null,
})

export const getters = {
  
  //----------------- Language and Direction
  lang(state){
    return state.lang
  },
  dir(state){
    return state.dir
  },
}

export const mutations = {
  SET_LANGUAGE(state, lang){
    state.lang = lang
  },
  SET_DIRECTION(state, dir){
    state.dir = dir
  },
}

export const actions = {
  
  async nuxtServerInit({dispatch, commit}) {
    // ------------- Read Language File
    let baseLang = process.env.SITE_LANGUAGE;
    let siteLang = langfile[baseLang];
    let siteDir = langfile[baseLang]['dir'];
    commit('SET_LANGUAGE', siteLang);
    commit('SET_DIRECTION', siteDir);
    
    
  },
}
```

Comment: What are you exporting in the `store` file ?

Comment: @MichalLevý Updated with my store index.js

Comment: @MojtabaBarari do u find the way to access vuex from nuxt plugins?

Comment: @PutraFajarHasanuddin, no, for my case had to add a mixin , import the part of plugin that wanted to extend, and extended it in the `mounted` hook of mixin