# how to define global variables in Nuxt to be accessed anywhere

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

as i start to expand my app, i found a big problem!! i'm developing a multilingual bidirectional app without `i18n`. basically i have a language json file like bellow:

```
{
  "fa":{
    "dir": "rtl",
    // ....
  },
  "en":{
    "dir": "ltr",
    //....
  }
}
```

i store it in my vuex state `lang` on nuxtInitServer. but i have two problem.

first, how to access it in my scss file to change the font family?

second, how to access it in my plugins?
as for plugins, here is my explanation: [link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63847092/how-to-get-access-to-vuex-inside-other-js-files-like-plugins-in-nuxt)

btw, is there any way to define a global variable in nuxt to be acessed anywhere, and of course be changable (not static like env). for example when i change language, be able to access current language in .js and .scss files.

**UPDATE**
here is my actual plugin code that needs access to store:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { required, email , alpha , alpha_spaces , numeric , confirmed } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules'
import { extend, ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider, setInteractionMode } from 'vee-validate'
import { store } from 'vuex'

Vue.prototype.$something= function (){
    let lang = store.state.lang
}

setInteractionMode('eager')

extend('required', {
    ...required,
    message: `{_field_} ${$lang.error_required}` // this is were i'm gonna use my vuex state
})
extend('email', email)
extend('alpha', alpha)
extend('numeric', numeric)
extend('alpha_spaces', alpha_spaces)
extend('confirmed', confirmed)
extend("decimal", {
    validate: (value, { decimals = '*', separator = '.' } = {}) => {
        if (value === null || value === undefined || value === '') {
            return {
                valid: false
            };
        }
        if (Number(decimals) === 0) {
            return {
                valid: /^-?\d*$/.test(value),
            };
        }
        const regexPart = decimals === '*' ? '+' : `{1,${decimals}}`;
        const regex = new RegExp(`^[-+]?\\d*(\\${separator}\\d${regexPart})?([eE]{1}[-]?\\d+)?$`);

        return {
            valid: regex.test(value),
        };
    },
    message: '{_field_} ' + ''
})
Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider);
Vue.component("ValidationObserver", ValidationObserver);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can not access a javascript variable in Scss Code. But you could define a Css class for each locale and set the right class to a main div with a computed property inside your layout file.

```
<template>
  <div :class="containerLangClass">
    <nuxt />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    containerLangClass() {
      return "container-" + this.$store.getters.lang;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.container-fa {
  font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
}
.container-en {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

2. You can import the vuex store in your plugin and use it in custom methods, directives and co. but I think you want to access the store values before the plugin is created.

So you can't just import the store

```
import {store} from './store';
```

and use its values like

```
store.getters.lang
```

because at this point the store is not initialized.

**UPDATE**
Of course you can use store getters, actions etc. in a custom function like:

```
import Vue from "vue";

Vue.prototype.$something = function (){
            
let lang = this.$store.getters.lang; //...etc

        }
```

**UPDATE 2**
To use your store in your custom validation message, you could add a mixin where you add your validation in the mounted hook. At this point you have all access to your vuex store.

plugin code:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { extend } from "vee-validate";
import { required } from "vee-validate/dist/rules";

Vue.mixin({
  mounted() {
    extend("required", {
      ...required,
      message: fieldName => {
        return `${fieldName} ${this.$store.getters.$lang.error_required}`;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Be aware that this code will get called everytime when mounted is called. So I would recommend just using this validation in the pages where you need it.

Comment: i tried this but get `"export 'store' was not found in 'vuex'` error in my cmd . also lang won't be defined! i updated my issue with the plugin code that i want store access in it. also tried to use `$something` and using your code in another js file and import it here, but no luck

Comment: My mistake, sorry for that! you can't import the store like "import  {store} from "vuex" ". I just fixed my answer.

Comment: so i can't access my store in my plugins!? that validation is `vee-validate` module and that code is for it's config in `plugins` folder, `veevalidate.js` file . if i wanted to use it on each page, i could config it on that page script part. using a mixin i think gonna make it complicated!

Comment: the mixin code I wrote, represents the veevalidate.js file in the plugins folder. So you have to write it just once. As I said, it is possible to access the store within a custom prototype function (UPDATE 1) but you don't have access to the registered store within the main plugin scope. (Where you called the extend method). That's why I'm adding it to the mounted hook, so you can easily register your custom validation and return your store variable. The mixing is there, to register it in every page.